# Should a file-scope variable in C be marked static compulsorily? What's the scope of a non-static variable defined in a ".c" file and not in header?

Tags: c, global-variables

```cpp
//Engine.c

// API is the conditional macro which replaces __declspec(dllexport) or __declspec(dllimport)
// according to a predefined macro

WindowInterface windowHandle;

API void CreateInternalWindowHandle(
    const char* titleBar, unsigned short width, unsigned short height, WindowMode mode) {
    windowHandle.Width = width;
    windowHandle.Height = height;
    windowHandle.Mode = mode;
    CreateInternalWindowInterface(&windowHandle, titleBar);
}

API WindowInterface* GetWindowInterface() {
    return &windowHandle;
}
```

```cpp
//Engine.h

API void CreateInternalWindowHandle(
    const char* titleBar, unsigned short width, unsigned short height, WindowMode mode);

API WindowInterface* GetWindowInterface();
```

```cpp
//Renderer.c

WindowInterface* windowHandle;

void Renderer_Init(WindowInterface* window) {
    windowHandle = window;

    // ..Some code here..

    {
        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC desc;
        // ..Some code here..
        
        // This calls works properly
        desc.OutputWindow = glfwGetWin32Window((GLFWwindow*)(window->nativeWindowHandle));
        // ..Some code here..
    }

    // ..Rest of init code..

    // Inside this function, the value of windowHandle->Width and windowHandle->Height
    // changes to some garbage value, even though I am not modifying it inside the function
    RenderResize((int)(windowHandle->Width), (int)(windowHandle->Height));
}
```

As mentioned in the above code snippets through comments - when I access the variable `windowHandle` of `Engine.c` via a pointer which is passed down to the Renderer's `Init` function, the data inside it get corrupted. The `WindowInterface` struct has three variables which are not pointers, and all three are getting assigned some random garbage values.

Oddly, when I marked the `windowHandle` variable as `static`, the whole setup works properly.

I want to know why is the above behavior observed. Is making the variable `static` the only solution to this oddity?
I want to have a complete idea of the lifetime/scope of the variable, where it's defined, and means of observing access to the variable, hence one getter method which returns a pointer.

Not sure whether marking the variable `static` exposes the variable to other translation units / `.c` files. Or worse, the executable linking to the dll is able to access the variable directly through the dll interface.

Comment: Why have you tagged a C question with the C++ tag?

Comment: Non-static variables in namespace-scope have [*external linkage*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#External_linkage). They can be used by any [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) with a proper declaration.

Comment: Someone who's using C++ in a more C-like way would also be able to answer this, hence I tagged C++ as well.

Comment: Rename `windowHandle` to `myOwnFancyWindowHandle` in both renderer,c and engine.c and tell us what happens.

Comment: why would it not be tagged C++? The answer is about scoping and Translation units and will most likely be valid for both languages (and if the answer differs in the two languages, that would be very interesting and noteworthy for people working in both languages)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Alright, so if a variable is not marked static, then in another translation unit, if we declare/define a variable with the same **variable name** , their will be discrepancies.

So, if we are planning on not marking variables which are supposed to be scoped to a single translation unit as static, rule of thumb is to use unique variable names.

Also, that means using `static` be considered a rule-of-thumb as well in this case.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, that got it working.

Comment: @julaine From the tag description: "C is distinct from C++ and it should not be combined with the C++ tag without a specific reason." Such a specific reason might be of the question is about using C and C++ together or about differences between both languages. The fact that you might succeed in compiling with both compilers is not a specific reason. In short: Tag the language that is actually used, not all languages you can think about.

Comment: Avoid global variables.

Comment: @AllanWind Will try to implement in that manner. But there will be some data which I would like to persist for the duration of the program - window state, resize width, resize height, or the function pointers to which functions are assigned during application init stage.

Comment: @UjjwalRaut: Re “Someone who's using C++ in a more C-like way would also be able to answer this, hence I tagged C++ as well”: Do not do that. There is a policy about using the tags. When you tag a question, you attract attention of people following that tag and hence consume their time. Their time is donaed, and you should respect its value. A person who knows C++ and wants to help with C questions will follow the C tag, and tagging C++ will not help get their attention. A person who does not want to help with C will not follow the C tag, and tagging C++ is a rude claim on their time.

Comment: @UjjwalRaut: Additionally, answers between the two languages vary, and tagging C++ for what is actually a C question harms future Stack Overflow users who search for answers to a C++ question and get results that are specific to C and are not what they are looking for in C++. Use the tags with respect for the community, not for what helps you particularly.

Comment: You do you but global variables makes your code hard to reason about and hard to test.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Alright, got it.

Comment: @AllanWind Alright, got it.

Comment: If you don't have a header to declare the variable in, it should be `static` so that it cannot be referenced from outside the source file.  If I had my way, functions and file scope variables would be static by default, requiring a marker to indicate that they are intended to be available in other source files.  Sadly, it's 50 years too late for that.  It would require a more regimented language than the original C — or even modern standard C.  Nevertheless, IMNSHO, your attitude should be that all functions and variables should be `static` unless they are actually accessed in another file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Understood. Coming from a primarily C++ background, I didn't have and idea that in C, variables defined in such a manner would still be exposed to other modules. Also that begets the purpose of header file for the corresponding `.c` file in such a case.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks for pointing it out, you are correct. Can't say I like it but I will respect it.